# generic repository pattern ,any alternative?

Tags: entity-framework

I have read many pages regarding repository pattern,tons of them are online and each of them starts with we should use it because it makes the application testable  and also separation matters,but i also see many opinions against this pattern,or also they say its depends on the application which approach to take,all in all the thing is implementation of the logic must be kept away from controller,can anyone tell me how can i do it if generic repository is not the first option?im new in entity framework

Comment: IMO a (custom) generic repository wrapping the EF types is an anti-pattern. The type `DbContext` is an implementation of a UoW pattern and the type `DbSet<T>` is an implementation of a Generic Repository pattern. Why re-wrap these types in your own implementation of the same pattern? You would be adding nothing of value, just more code and a poor abstraction which results in code that is harder to read, debug, and use.

Comment: @Igor so,evrything should be implemnted in controller ?

Comment: That depends on the functionality. For a small app thats no issue. For larger or more complex apps you would abstract functionality into reusable services or components. There are many architectures you can pick from (onion, domain driven design, etc).

Comment: As Igor said, wrapping EF in a repository doesn't actually give you anything more than what you get with EF.